# selecting proper value of spinner according to my Class

Tags: java, android

i am making an edit Screen of my Account.

My account class has some properties. Now i want to show these properties and then edit them.
I Have made a spinner that shows the account type.

Right now i am using this code

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> typeOfAccountAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                        this, R.array.typeOfAccountArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
               typeOfAccount.setAdapter(typeOfAccountAdapter); 

                typeOfAccount.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
                 {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
                    {
                        if (typeOfAccount.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Income"))
                            myAccount.accountType = AccountType.kAccountTypeIncome;
                        else if(typeOfAccount.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Asset"))
                            myAccount.accountType = AccountType.kAccountTypeAsset;
                        else if(typeOfAccount.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Cash"))
                            myAccount.accountType = AccountType.kAccountTypeAssetCash;
                        else if(typeOfAccount.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bank"))
                            myAccount.accountType = AccountType.kAccountTypeAssetBank;
                        else if(typeOfAccount.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Liability"))
                            myAccount.accountType = AccountType.kAccountTypeLiability;
                        else
                            myAccount.accountType = AccountType.kAccountTypeLiabilityOther;
                        setStrDeatilOfAccount();
                    }
```

This code actually instead of displaying `myAccount.accountType`, sets the first element of `spinner` as `accountType` of my account.

How can i display not the first item of array of `typeOfAccountArray` but `accountType` of `myAccount`

And then i can edit and change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String yourAccountTypeInString;
               if (myAccount.accountType == yourAccountType)
                   yourAccountTypeInString= "theStringOfAccountType";
         // use else if 

               int pos = typeOfAccountAdapter.getPosition(yourAccountTypeInString);
               typeOfAccount.setSelection(pos);
```

Try this and Tell

Answer (score 0):

```
 typeOfAccount.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
             {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
                {  
       constants_class.GROUP=(String) typeOfAccountAdapter.getItem(arg2).toString();
        if(constants_class.GROUP.equalsIgnoreCase("Income")){

        }
        else if(constants_class.GROUP.equalsIgnoreCase("Asset")){

        }  
       else if(constants_class.GROUP.equalsIgnoreCase("Asset")){

        }
}});
```

And default spinner take the first value but when you click on spinner and select any item it will take correct..Hope this will helpfull to you